# Rectangle interaction with polyline

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I am using Cesium JS to create a 2D map.
I am using the following code to get the Cesium camera rectangle points coordinates:

```
var result = new Cesium.Rectangle();
scene.camera.computeViewRectangle(Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84, result);
var northWest = new Cesium.Cartographic();
var northEast = new Cesium.Cartographic();
var southWest = new Cesium.Cartographic();
var southEast = new Cesium.Cartographic();

Cesium.Rectangle.northeast(result, northEast);
Cesium.Rectangle.northwest(result, northWest);
Cesium.Rectangle.southeast(result, southEast);
Cesium.Rectangle.southwest(result, southWest);
```

this way I am getting all the rectangle coordinates.
I have a polyline that is starting at a Cesium entity inside the camera view and is intersecting with the camera view rectangle.

How can I find out if the polyline is interacting with the rectangle and what is the coordinate of the interaction?

Comment: Do you mean *intersecting?

Comment: In cesium when you get the camera view coordinates it returns the 4 corners coordinate in a rectangle object, I need to find out if my line "cut" one of the rectangle lines, and if the answer is yes, what are the cut point coordinates?

Comment: Treat each edge as a separate line segment intersection problem. In 2D this is a linear system with two equations.